# Получить измененные данные и внести в json файл

Tags: javascript, axios

я только начал изучать js и передо мной встала задача.
Я использовал библиотеку Tabulator для создания таблицы из json файла, расположенного на сервере.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  reactiveData:true,
  ajaxURL:"/data.json",
  ajaxContentType:"json"
```

Все подгружается и редактируется верно.
Я могу скачать отредактированный файл в формате json с помощью Tabulator.

```
document.getElementById("download-json").addEventListener("click", function() {
  table.download("json", "data.json");
});
```

Но как я могу внести изменения в файл который подгружается из таблицы, то есть перезаписать его с измененными пользователем ячейками. Я пробовал делать это через axios, но кажется делаю это не верно.

Comment: `axios` - не для изменений, а для запросов к серверу.  Приведите код где вы пытаетесь делать изменения.

Comment: `document.getElementById("file-upload-trigger").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var data = table.getData();
  
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/data.json',`

Comment: Так тут вы получаете данные. Где вы их изменяете?

Comment: Ну вот в этом и вопрос, что я делаю не так, чтобы передать данные из таблицы в файл?

Comment: Вы знаете как получить ссылку на элемент и взять значение элемента?

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, данные таблицы можно получить через
var data = table.getData();

Comment: отправьте полученные данные на сервер, обработайте, запишите в хранилище (БД/файл/etc.)